# Прямоугольники html

Tags: html

Мне нужно отрисовать прямоульник по координатам двух точек и с определенным цветом. Я делаю программу типа сервер-клиент на с#, где клиент посылает серверу запрос с координатами двух точек и цветом. А сервер рисует прямоугольник. Нагуглил подходящий способ через SVG, но не знаю как здесь задать координаты двух точек. Именно чтобы автоматически ширина и высота подбиралась по ним. Если так нельзя, то можно высчитывать ширину и высоту с помощью второй координаты как раз, ну и потом дописать их в тег. Ну и еще есть способ рисовать через прямые. Как мне лучше это сделать?

Пример, который я нашел:

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" color="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Высота и ширина - чего? `rect`'а или холста `svg`?

Comment: И данные с сервера принимаете как? Сразу встраиваете в страницу через C#, PHP, или же JS используете?

Comment: И какие именно две точки? 

Comment: Извиняюсь,не уточнил,что координаты двух углов.левый верхний и нижний правый.Высота и ширина rect, а не svg. И да,встраиваю сразу в страницу через с#.

Comment: все-таки думаю,что лучше будет сделать расчет ширины и высоты исходя из координат : width = x1 - x0, height = y1 - y0

Comment: Именно так, причём `width = abs(x1 - x0)` и `height = abs(y1- y0)`. Так же для `svg` лучше указывать размер холста `viewbox` атрибут.

Comment: понял, спасибо.